# How to write that layout XML in a template file?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, phtml

This is my layout XML:

```
<block type="amazonpayments/pay_button" name="product.info.addtocart.amazonpayments" template="creativestyle/amazonpayments/pay/product/button.phtml" before="-">
            <action method="setIdSuffix"><value>product</value></action>
            <action method="setEnableOr"><value>1</value></action>
            <action method="setIsProductButton"><value>1</value></action>
        </block>
```

I used this code in my template file but I think the parameters (like setIdSuffix) are missing:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('amazonpayments/pay_button')->setTemplate('creativestyle/amazonpayments/pay/product/button.phtml')->toHtml();
```

This gives no errors but the corresponding button is not shown either. Any ideas what might be wrong?

**Magento 1.9**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code:

```
$data = array('id_suffix' => 'product', 'enable_or' => 1, 'is_product_button' => 1) 
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('amazonpayments/pay_button', 'product.info.addtocart.amazonpayments', $data)->setTemplate('creativestyle/amazonpayments/pay/product/button.phtml')->toHtml();
```

You can check the method **createBlock()** under:

> app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php

They receiving 3 parameters, 1 is type, 2 is name and 3 is data. I have passing the data by creating an array to it. So it should work now.